# ElasticSearch 2.0 Java API: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

I have updated my Spring Boot project to use the new ElasticSearch 2 API and I get this error at startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/settings/ImmutableSettings$Builder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
```

My relevant Maven dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do you have any hint on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES 2.0, the `ImmutableSettings` class was indeed removed. [This issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13151) mentions it and the [breaking changes documentation for 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_java_api_changes.html#_immutablesettings_removed) also mention it.

Instead you can now use `Settings.builder()` instead of `ImmutableSettings.builder()`. The current implementation of the `Settings` class can be seen [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/148265bd164cd5a614cd020fb480d5974f523d81/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/Settings.java)

All the questions that still use `ImmutableSettings` are questions about **pre-2.0 versions** of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Ok, I guess that the spring-data-elasticsearch component is making that call when initiating the local client. Do you know if there is a workaroud for that? Or any version of that component that support the new 2.0 API? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain that Spring Boot already provides an ES-2.0 compatible release. They are probably waiting for the GA release. You might be able to check out the project and make a custom build which uses the ES 2.0 libs.