# which function can i use instead of ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder() in elasticsearch 2.1

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The ImmutableSettings class in the elastic-search project does not exist anymore. I found that the class was deleted.

I uses the function settingsBuilder() in ImmutableSetting class but Now it is removed. does any one suggest me which function am I going to use instead of > ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().

I use this function as below.

> `ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name",properties.getProperty(ELS_CLUSTER_NAME)).put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch 2.0 Java API: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277072/elasticsearch-2-0-java-api-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-elasticsearch)

Comment: I have already verified that but I can't get the solution.In that link shows use Settings.Builder(). but it won't work that's y I raise the separate question.Can u suggest me that what I can use instead of ImmutableSettings. settingBuildet() method

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't work"? What error do you get?

Comment: Hi @Val Thanks for ur response After I change the code from immutable settings into settings class I got the following Error **nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FAIL_ON_SYMBOL_HASH_OVERFLOW** Kindly suggest some solution for that.

Comment: What version of the Java client library do you have and what exact version of ES do you have?

Comment: After updating the ES I'm using JEST 2.0.0 as a java client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99396/discussion-between-mohan-and-val).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, though according to the error you mention, you have conflicting dependencies on the Jackson library.

What can happen is that you depend on one version of the Jackson library and some other dependency references another version of the same library. At runtime, the wrong JAR is loaded (probably an ancient one with a version lower than 2.3) and hence the error you're seeing.

You need to figure out where the conflict is. You can do this with `mvn dependency:tree` ([how to solve conflicts](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)) in order to see where the conflict takes its root. Once you have pinpointed the faulty library you can [exclude a specific dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) for a specific library in your POM in order to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently upgraded from 1.7 to 2.1.1 and this is the change I had to make:

```
    Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
    TransportClient client = new TransportClient.Builder().settings(settings).build();
    client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```